# How to send reminder to attendee of the appointment (not the owner of shared calendar) 24 hr before the appointment time in outlook 2013?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, appointment

I am creating a windows application in C# for setting appointments in a shared calendar for my team. I am the owner of the calendar. I have written the code to set the appointment and set reminder time as 24 hrs before the meeting. But instead of sending reminder to attendee it is sending reminder to me. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook for this. Here is the code that I used:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

// Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

// Get the Calendar folder.
Outlook.Recipient rcip = oNS.CreateRecipient("abc@domain.com");
Outlook.MAPIFolder oSharedCal = oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(rcip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.MAPIFolder oShiftCal = oSharedCal.Folders["Sample"];
// Get the Items (Appointments) collection from the Calendar folder.
Outlook.Items oItems = oSharedCal.Items;
Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppt = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)oItems.Add();

// Set Appointment properties.
oAppt.Subject = Subject;
oAppt.Start = start;
oAppt.End = end;
oAppt.RequiredAttendees = email;
oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 24 * 60; 
oAppt.ReminderSet = true;
oAppt.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olFree;

//Show the item to pause.
oAppt.Save();
oAppt.Send();
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please only use the [visual-studio] tag for questions about the tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

Reminders cannot be set for attendees, they are for your copy of the appointment in the calendar you create it in.  Attendees can set a reminder for themselves when the accept the meeting request.